# Running OS X on a virtual machine

Tags: macos, osx-lion, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I used this guide to install OS X on a virtual machine (Virtual Box).

http://www.macbreaker.com/2012/07/mountain-lion-virtualbox.html

There is a problem in step 4:

The installation stops when left 4 minutes to end

I tried to do the suggestions that people have brought responses down, nothing helped!

Anybody else encountered this and solved it in another way?

Comment: And this is a programming question and a good fit for this site?

Comment: I think so, I need the mac to program applications

Comment: I need my Mac to write applications. So by your logic, if my hard drive dies, or my video card starts acting funny - I should ask a question about it here? What if I need my car to get to work where I write applications? Say my car won't start in the morning - does that mean I can ask a question about it here? - because it does bear some relation to programming.

Comment: @HodayaShalom ask this question over at superuser.com

Comment: Abizern What are you so nervous? You have already voted down, I was just asking if anyone having this problem too, you do not have to answer ..

Comment: Thank you Slomojo, I ask

Comment: Really I did not know this site ...

Comment: Put it as an answer, you deserve the Bounty

Comment: If you remove the bounty we can vote to move it to SU.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is forbidden by Apple's software licensing to run OS X on non Apple hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install VirtualBox 4.2.6

VirtualBox 4.2.6

https   www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Set Architecture 32-bit Type – MacOS X.

64 bit MacOS X slow and bug in VM.

Get ISO, MacOS X Mountain Lion Install DVD 10.8.2 Intel:

MacOS X Mountain Lion Install DVD 10.8.2 Intel

http   rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4152164

Create virtual HDD fixed size 40Gb+, VDI(VirtualBox) or VDMK(Vmware WS) type.

Install MacOS in VirtualBox  3-4 hour.

MultiBeast - Mountain Lion 5.2.1

tonymacx86 Downloads MultiBeast - Mountain Lion 5.2.1

http   www.tonymacx86.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=155

82 pages screencast Pdf and Docx.

Screencast manual Install MacOS 10.8.2 Intel in VirtualBox

https   skydrive.live.com/?cid=4CD1B952A2640E72&id=4CD1B952A2640E72!233#

If need may add Screencast manual Install MacOS on Vmware WS.